# tkinter text box not showing variable

Tags: python, tkinter, beautifulsoup

I have the following (extracted) code:

```
web = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
b_price=web.find('div',{'class':'variation'}).p.contents[2]
a=tkinter.StringVar()
a.set(b_price)
print("B"+b_price)
#print (a.get())
p1.delete(0.0,tkinter.END)
p1.insert(0.0, a.get())
```

and gui is:

```
root=tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.Label(root,text="test").grid(row=0)
tkinter.Label(root, text="What?").grid(row=1)
e1=tkinter.Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=1,column=1)
tkinter.Button(root, text="quit",command=root.quit).grid(row=3,column=0)
tkinter.Button(root,text='show prices',command=show_prices).grid(row=3,column=1)
tkinter.Button(root,text='show webpages',command=show_webpages).grid(row=3,column=2)
tkinter.Label(root,text="Price a").grid(row=4, column=0)
tkinter.Label(root,text="Price b").grid(row=5, column=0)
p1=tkinter.Text(root,height=1,width=20)
p1.grid(row=4,column=1)
p1.insert(0.0, "a")
p2=tkinter.Text(root,height=1,width=20)
p2.grid(row=5,column=1)
p2.insert(0.0, "b")
root.mainloop()
```

the problem is that i cannot get the variable displayed into Textbox "p1". The code does delete the default text in textbox p1. I can print the contents of "a" in the shell with print(a.get()), I can print the contents of b_price in the shell and when I change p1.insert(0.0, a.get()) to p1.insert(0.0,"a") it displays "a" in the textbox.I'm just not able to display the b_price or a in the textbox. 
Does anyone got a clue what I'm missing?

Comment: There is not enough code to diagnose the problem, If `print(a.get())` works, then calling `p1.insert(0.0, a.get())` must also work, assuming they are called in the same context. The only explanations might be that you're calling `print` and `p1.insert` in different places in your code.  While you're mistakenly inserting at `0.0`, that doesn't really matter too much. However, the proper index for the first character is a string, with the line number starting at one: `"1.0"`.

Comment: Is the "extracted code" running in a different instance of `Tk` than the gui code? It's not clear how you are tying these two blocks of code together.

Comment: If the variable is a then why are you inserting "a"? It should just be a with no quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The result of the "web.find" started with a newline. After making the textbox two lines, it shows the result on the second line.